# Should business rules be enforced in both the application tier and the database tier, or just one of the two?

Tags: database, stored-procedures, business-rules, n-tier-architecture

I have been enforcing business rules in both my application tier (models) and my database tier (stored procedures who raise errors).

I've been duplicating my validations in both places for a few reasons:

1. If the conditions change between
   when they are checked in the
   application code and when they are
   checked in the database, the
   business rule checks in the database
   will save the day.  The database
   also allows me to lock various
   records in a simpler manner than in
   my application code, so it seems
   natural to do so here.
2. If we have
   to do some batch data
   insertions/updates to the database directly, if I route
   all these operations through my
   stored procedures/functions which
   are doing the business rule
   validations, there's no chance of me
   putting in bad data even though I lack the protections that I would get if I was doing single-input through the application.
3. While
   enforcing these things ONLY in the
   database would have the same effect
   on the actual data, it seems
   improper to just throw data at the
   database before first making a good
   effort to validate that it conforms
   to constraints and business rules.

What's the right balance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enforce at the data tier to ensure data integrity. That's your last line of defense, and that's the DBs job, to help enforce its world view of the data.

That said, throwing junk data against the DB for validation is a coarse technique. Typically the errors are designed to be human readable rather than machine readable, so its inefficient for the program to process the error from the DB and make heads or tails out of it.

Stored Procedures are a different matter. Back in the day, Stored Procedures were The Way to handle business rules on the data tiers, etc.

But today, with the modern application server environments, they have become a, in general, better place to put this logic. They offer multiple ways to access and expose the data (the web, web services, remote protocols, APIs, etc). Also, if your rules are CPU heavy (arguably most aren't) it's easier to scale app servers than DB servers.

The large array of features within the app servers give them a flexibility beyond what the DB servers can do, and thus much of what was once pushed back in to the DBs is being pulled out with the DB servers being relegated to "dumb persistence".

That said, there are certainly performance advantages using Stored Procs and such, but now that's a tuning thing where the question becomes "is it worth losing the app server capability for the gain we get by putting it in to the DB server".

And by app server, I'm not simply talking Java, but .NET and even PHP etc.

Comment: What's the difference between enforcement of business logic and enforcing data integrity?  Suppose I have a business rule that says at most 3 people can be assigned to a supervisor.  When I go to insert person #4, is that failing because it's a data integrity error to have > 3 people per supervisor, or is it a business rule breach?  Without locking the supervisor record prior to verification that there are at most 2 people under a supervisor when doing an insert, how can the application code be 100% sure that this rule will not be be broken?

Comment: @Rednerln - rate of change.  The database integrity rules are things likely to be assumed to be true for much longer than the business rules.  Your example of people to a supervisor, I would have a hard time justifying making that a database constraint, if I did, it would have to be data-based (udf based on a configuration setting).  And if the rule changes, one has to ask the question what to do about data which violates that principle.  Typically you want database rules which are only relaxed, not tightened or changed qualitatively.

Comment: @Rednerln - in multi-modal situations, you want people to be able to hit your DB access layer (views, perhaps) with their BI tools or whatever and know that their assumptions are valid, that the database has cohesion and integrity at its perimeter.

Answer (score 3):

Your business logic can sit in either location, but should not be in both.  The logic should NOT be duplicated because it's easy to make a mistake trying to keep both in sync.  If you put it in the model you'll want all data access to go through your models, including batch updates.

There will be trade-offs to putting it in the database vs the application models (here's a few of the top of my head):

- Databases can be harder to maintain and update than applications
- It's easier to distribute load if it's in the application tier
- Multiple, disparate dbs may require splitting business rules (which may not be possible)

Answer (score 3):

If the rule must be enforced at all times no matter where the data came from or how it was updated, the database is where it needs to be. Remember databases are affected by direct querying to make changes that affect many records or to do something the application would not normally do. These are things like fixing a group of records when a customer is bought out by another customer and they want to change all the historical data, the application of new tax rates to orders not yet processed, the fixing of a some bad data inputs. They are also affected sometimes by other applications which do not use your data layer. They may also be affected by imports run through ETL programs which also cannot use your data layer. So if the rule must in all cases be followed, it must be in the database.

If the rule is only for special cases concerning how this particular input page works, then it needs to be in the application. So if a sales manager has only specific things he can do from his user interface, these things can be specified in the application.

Somethings it is helpful to do in both places. For instance, it is silly to allow a user to put a non-date in an input box that will relate to a date field. The datatype in the database should still be a datetime datatype, but it is best to check some of this stuff before you send.